# How should stoning be carried out?

Tags: sharia, punishment, rajm

I have just watched "The Stoning Of Soraya M".
 In that movie she is stoned without hiding her hair. It is clearly a movie, so it might not show what happens in reality, so I sought out videos showing the real thing.

I found numerous examples on-line (links removed by masfenix. See revision history of this question if the sources are important to you), but they are inconsistent in details; in some videos the punished's hair is covered, but in others it is not.  Similarly, some videos have the punished be dug into the ground, and others do not.

**Question:**

I am confused here:
 I understand that the stoning comes from the hadith and not the quran ([Where do we get the idea of beheading, stoning and hand-mutilation in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/943/where-do-we-get-the-idea-of-beheading-stoning-and-hand-mutilation-in-islam/947#947)), but where does it say **how** the stoning should be done?

Comment: Do you think you could remove the highly offensive videos?

Comment: Simple curiosity.

Comment: you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajm wiki page, their is some information in fiqh section. Also it must be kept in mind that rajm was not a new kind of punishment, it was an old punishment which was also practiced by Jews of that time, so there was nothing new to explain. Though we find how some RAJAM punishments were executed in ahadith. Also have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoning

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

**Firstly:**
You should read [rajm-wikipedia](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajm) page, their is some information in fiqh section. Also it must be kept in mind that **rajm/stoning was not a new kind of punishment, it was an old punishment which was also practiced by Jews of that time(it was present in their scriptures too), so there was nothing new to explain.** Though we find how some RAJAM punishments were executed in ahadith. Also have a look at [stonning-wikipedia](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoning) to have a look at stonning history.

Below is an **incident of stoning a jew in era of prophet Muhammad peace be upon him**

> Narrated Ibn 'Umar: **A Jew and a Jewess were brought to Allah's Apostle
>   on a charge of committing an illegal sexual intercourse**. The Prophet
>   asked them. "What is the legal punishment (for this sin) in your Book
>   (Torah)?" They replied, "Our priests have innovated the punishment of
>   blackening the faces with charcoal and Tajbiya." **'Abdullah bin Salam
>   said, "O Allah's Apostle, tell them to bring the Torah." The Torah was
>   brought, and then one of the Jews put his hand over the Divine Verse
>   of the Rajam (stoning to death) and started reading what preceded and
>   what followed it. On that, Ibn Salam said to the Jew, "Lift up your
>   hand." Behold! The Divine Verse of the Rajam was under his hand. So
>   Allah's Apostle ordered that the two (sinners) be stoned to death**, and
>   so they were stoned. Ibn 'Umar added: So both of them were stoned at
>   the Balat and I saw the Jew sheltering the Jewess.  
> Sahih Bukhari
>   8:82:809, See also: Sahih Bukhari 6:60:79, and Sahih Bukhari 4:56:829

and this is also similar

> Narrated 'Abdullah bin 'Umar : **The Jew brought to the Prophet a man
>   and a woman from amongst them who have committed (adultery) illegal
>   sexual intercourse.** He ordered both of them **to be stoned (to death),
>   near the place of offering the funeral prayers beside the mosque**."
>   Sahih Bukhari 2:23:413

Secondly, lets have a look at some other ahadith about stoning execution:

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah and Zayd ibn Khaalid al-Juhani (may
>   Allaah be pleased with them both) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “… Go tomorrow, O Unays, to
>   this woman and **if she admits (to adultery) then stone her**.” He said: I
>   went to her the next day and she admitted it, so the Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) ordered that she be
>   stoned.” 
> Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 2575; Muslim, 1698.

And

> It was narrated from Jaabir that a man from (the tribe of) Aslam came
>   to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) when he was
>   in the mosque and **he said, “I have committed adultery.”**  The Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) turned his face away from
>   him. The man came to that side to which the Prophet had turned his
>   face, and testified against himself four times. **The Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, "Are you mad?” He said, “No.”
>   The Prophet said, “Are you married?" He said, "Yes.” So he commanded
>   that he be stoned in the Musalla (Eid prayer place). When the stones
>   troubled him, he ran away, until he was caught in al-Harrah and
>   killed.**
>
> Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4969; Muslim, 1691.

Lets just stay with these here, there are also some other which have similar meanings.
**It is clear form these incidents that rajam is to be done in public place, as it mentions prayer ground besides mosque in hadith.**
And from the last hadith it is clear that he ran, meaning he was not burried half in earth(as some fiqh say so, i don't know about their evidence for this), only than he could had ran.
In hanafi school of thought *In cases of self-confession, the accused is neither bound nor partially buried and allowed to escape during stoning. In the other case, according to Hanafi legal texts, the accused is bound and partially buried inside a bit in standing position so he or she cannot escape, and then stoning must be performed till he or she dies.* From [stonning section here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanafi)

**Lastly there is no rocket science in meaning of stonning to death, it means, the person will be stoned until he dies**(same as cutting hand of thief means just cut his hand of... no need to precisely mark where to cut and so on. Cut the hand and that's it.)! Also it does not need to be mentioned that the punishment is to be carried out by government.
**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I am not a mufti and all of this is based on my research and my understanding which can be wrong and must not be trusted. Pleas correct me if you find anything wrong in it.

### Allah knows best

Comment: Adding a reason for downvote would be really helpful though.